# $\mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R$ is an Integral Domain or a Division Ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone help me with these two doubts of mine:

1. Is the ring $\mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R$ an Integral Domain or a Division Ring?
2. My notes state that the ring of Gaussian integers(i.e. $\mathbb Z[i]=\{a+bi~~\big|a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$) is not a field although it is an integral Domain.  *I don't understand which element in this ring does not have a multiplicative inverse*.

Kindly help with these two doubts of mine. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How do you define multiplication on the structure?

Comment: @quid I define multiplication in $\mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$ as usual multiplication under dot product...

Comment: Well $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an Euclidean ring with norm $N(a+ib)=a^{2}+b^{2}$. And the necessary and sufficient condition that $a\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unit is $N(a)=N(1)=1$. So the elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ which have multiplicative inverse are precisely those $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}$ which satisfy $a^{2}+b^{2}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question:

1. this can be considered as a subset of the complex numbers.
2. recall that the inverse must be **in the ring too** (not just some complex number that would exist).
3. observe that the square of the absolute value of every number in the ring is an integer, it is $a^2+ b^2$. Therefore, an element can be only invertible if its absolute value is $1$. Every other element cannot be invertible.

For the first, it depends on how you define multiplication: if you define it coordinate wise, that is $(a,b)(c,d)= (ac,bd)$ which is what I assume you mean (though this is not really the dot product which would be $ac+bd$ and not yield a composition law at all), then you have zero-divisors for example $(3,0)(0,9)=(0,0)$ and the structure thus is neither an integral domain nor a division ring.

Comment: just make me clear with 1 thing why is $\mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R $ not a division ring from your explanation..

Comment: A division ring cannot have any zero-divisors, as a zero-divisor cannot be invertible. But you might prefer a direct argument: it is not a division ring since for example $(2,0)(a,b)= (2a,0)$ and thus $(2,0)$ is not invertible as $(2,0)(a,b)\neq (1,1)$ for each $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

1) $\mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R$ is not a Domain, since $(1,0)$ is a divisor of zero, so it can't be either a Division Ring.

2) I think 2 hasn't an inverse..